# Jquery popup over popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a jquery popup which is opened using.

```
$('#id').popup('open');
```

The above popup contains an image whose `onclick` function should open one more popup above the previous popup, while retaining the previous popup, with the second popup overlapping the previously opened popup.

Tried out all the options available on stackoverflow, code pen, etc..

Comment: what you want to do exactly?

Comment: dispaly one small poup over another already opened large popup....

Answer (score 3):

I've came across this kind of situation, and i found that usually two popups one over another are not the best solution for a good end user interaction, especially if you don't want the user to interact simultaneously with both popups.

I suggest you a simple solution that could help you:

You can think your popup structure as a container of multiple popups, all hidden, and shown when needed with javascript.

example:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zn2S/1/)

```
    <body>

    <div id="popup">

        <section class="show">
            <h1> Hello i'm the content of the first popup </h1>
            <p> Please assume that i'm an actual popup as my actual structure it's not important for this example</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1> Hello i'm the content of the <strong>second</strong> popup </h1>
            <p> Please assume that i'm an actual popup as my actual structure it's not important for this example</p>      
        </section>
        <div class="button">Switch Popups</div>
    </div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").on("click", function () {
        $("#popup")
            .find(".show")
            .removeClass("show")
            .insertBefore(".button");

        $("#popup").children("section").eq(0).addClass("show");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/fd4o3o6s/

I wrote my own popup code.

Following code should work to open a popup on top of another popup,

```
var buttons = [{text:"Close popup"},{text:"Open second popup", value:true, close:false}];
var buttons2 = [{text:"Close popup"}];

new popup(buttons, "First popup", "<p>Some text.</p>").open().progress(function(r) {
    if(r) {
        new popup(buttons2, "Second popup", "<p>Some text.</p>").open();
    }
});
```